# Windowing function in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that is made up of companies. Each company has a "number_of_employees" as well as a subdocument of "offices" which includes "state_code" and "country_code". For example:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('52cdef7c4bab8bd675297da5'),
    'name': 'Technorati',
    'number_of_employees': 35,
    'offices': [
        {'description': '',
        'address1': '360 Post St. Ste. 1100',
        'address2': '',
        'zip_code': '94108',
        'city': 'San Francisco',
        'state_code': 'CA',
        'country_code': 'USA',
        'latitude': 37.779558,
        'longitude': -122.393041}
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the number of employees per state across all companies. My latest attempt looks like:

```
db.research.aggregate([
    { "$match": {"offices.country_code": "USA" } },
    { "$unwind": "$offices" },
    { "$project": { "_id": 1, "number_of_employees": 1, "offices.state_code": 1 } }
    ])
```

But now I'm stuck on how to do the `$group`. Because the `num_of_employees` is at the company level and not the office level I want to split them evenly across the offices. For example, if Technorati has 5 offices in 5 different states then each state would be allocated 7 employees.

In SQL I could do this easily enough using a windowed function to get average employees across offices by company and then summing those while grouping by state. I can't seem to find any clear examples of similar functionality in MongoDB though.

Note, this is for a school assignment, so the use of third-party libraries isn't feasible. Also, I'm hoping that this can all be done in a simple snippet of code, possibly even one call. I could certainly create new intermediate collections or do this in Python and process data there, but that's probably outside of the scope of the homework.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot "get the number of employees **per state** across all companies" neither in mongo nor SQL nor any other language because you don't have this information at the first place.

You have only total number of number_of_employees **per company**, and each company can have "offices" in different states. How do split 35 employees of Technorati if it had 2 offices - one in CA and the other in AZ ?

Comment: I explained *exactly* that in my question. I'm splitting them evenly across offices. I realize that it's not perfect, but it's the best that I can do (and I've already pointed out this deficiency to the professor).

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jWHWn9i0N4J) what you are looking for?

Comment: ah, indeed, missed this part. So if it is an approximation, half a person is not a problem right?

Comment: @ray With a bit of tweaking to get the rounding the way that I wanted it, that worked perfectly, thanks! If you put it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually on the right track. You just need to derive an extra field `numOfEmpPerOffice` by using `$divide` and `$sum` it when `$group` by state.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "offices.country_code": "USA"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "numOfEmpPerOffice": {
        "$divide": [
          "$number_of_employees",
          {
            "$size": "$offices"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$offices"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$offices.state_code",
      totalEmp: {
        $sum: "$numOfEmpPerOffice"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jWHWn9i0N4J) for your reference.